# C++ alias for global namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I use Visual Studio to create programs in C++ for Windows. I wonder what the best method is to write Windows API functions (including macros) as if they were part of a namespace, e.g. WinAPI. I used to define a macro that is empty, so the preprocessor deletes it, and only the :: will stay in the code, which means global scope:

```
#define WinAPI
BOOL bResult = WinAPI::SetWindowText( hwnd, L"Test Text" );

// After preprocessing:
BOOL bResult = ::SetWindowText( hwnd, L"Test Text" );
```

However, I ran into problems with macros, like ListBox_AddString; moreover I don't think that my solution was neat.

I would like to see at first glance whether a function call is part of Windows API, or one of my functions with a similar name. Is there a solution which uses namespaces somehow instead of an empty macro?

**Update**

I tried to implement Richard Hodges' proposal (using Visual Studio 2010):

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    int APIENTRY wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR szCmdLine, int iShowCmd )
//...
}
```

First I received LNK1561: entry point must be defined, so I set Project Properties > Linker > Linker > Advanced > Entry Point = MyNamespace::wWinMain

Then I received LNK1221: a subsystem can't be inferred and must be defined, so I set Project Properties > Linker > Linker > System > SubSystem = Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Now it compiles, links and runs, but iShowCmd is 0x7efde000 (a value I cannot interpret) instead of the usual (SW_SHOW = 0x00000001).

What is wrong?

Comment: I think you'll find that it's more productive to put all your application's classes and functions in an `app` namespace, and treat the global namespace as belonging to the 'current system environment'. The global namespace is always already polluted with c libraries, windows, posix, etc. You can't avoid that.

Comment: @Incomputable - that won't work. The name `SetWindowText` is not `WinAPI::SetWindowText`. In general, you can't wedge headers into a namespace that they were't designed for.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I think I misunderstood name resolution mechanism. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Incomputable To expand on the comment by Pete Becker, the symbol `SetWindowText` is actually macro. Depending on the `UNICODE` macro it's either a macro that is expanded to `SetWindowTextA` or `SetWindowTextW`. The same goes for just about *all* WINAPI functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks, I forgot that unsuffixed names are macros.

Comment: @Incomputable, even if the "function" were not a macro, putting the include into a namespace declaration only works for header-only functions. Most library functions have a binary counterpart in the DLL and the header declaration must match the symbol name in the DLL. Putting a function into a namespace changes the symbol name, so no function in that header would be usable anymore (linker would report unresolved symbols).

Comment: Putting aside the issue of whether `SetWindowText` is a macro (and oversimplifying a bit), each of the Windows libraries contains functions that have names that were defined when the library was compiled. You can't change those names without recompiling the library. So if a library has a function named `foo` and your program calls a function named `WinAPI::foo`, the linker will treat those as two different functions, and calls to `WinAPI::foo` will simply be unresolved names, because there is no function named `WinAPI::foo`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, so it seems like my misunderstanding was bigger than I thought. Thanks for making me less ignorant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll find that it's more productive to put all your application's classes and functions in an app namespace, and treat the global namespace as belonging to the 'current system environment'.

The global namespace is always already polluted with c libraries, windows, posix, OSX, etc.

You can't avoid that, since there are no operating systems with only a c++ API.

Comment: I don't see, that this would mark the points where the execution leaves my code and continues in an 'external' module, e.g.
namespace N
{
 class C : public B
 {
  void f()
  {
   SetWindowText( hwnd, L"Test Text" );
   /* May be N::C::SetWindowText, N::B::SetWindowText, N::SetWindowText, ::SetWindowText */
  }
 };
}
Or do you always write N::C::f even if you are in another member function of N::C?

Comment: @z32a7ul you must have heard the expression, "in c++ there is pedantic and there is wrong". :-) If there is the possibility for ambiguity then it's better to express the namespace explicitly. So I'd prefer `::SetWindowText(...)`. However, I would only ever call a system function from within some kind of conceptual wrapper as I'm always seeking decouple program logic from the execution environment as much as possible.